# Find variable and store values

Tags: excel, vba

I need to find a text string and store the item names below the text string to put in a different location in the sheet

Example I want to find "Description" and store all the items below it to use later in the macro

[image]

And place them in B1 for example

[image]

Here's the code im trying to use but I don't know how to store the Active Range

```
Sub test()

'find description
Cells.Find(What:="Description", After:=ActiveCell, LookIn:=xlValues, _
  LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
  MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False).Activate


Selection.Offset(1, 0).Select 'Offset after find
Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Select 'Selects to end

Dim DescriptionValues As Range
DescriptionValues = Active.Range

ActiveSheet.Range("B10") = DescriptionValues 'put stored text starting in B1

End Sub
```

Comment: When you say "...to later use in the macro", what are you going to do with it later? One option is to store all of the values in an array, which you can use later. This has the benefit of not having to actually place it on the worksheet, but store it in a variable.  It's also a little faster.  As you have it, try doing `ActiveSheet.Range("B1:B10").Value = DescriptionValues.Value` (I'm away from Excel, but that may work)

Comment: @BruceWayne Paste it in a different location along with 7 other stored value ranges.

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub test()
Dim rng As Range

Set rng = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find(What:="Description", After:=ActiveSheet.Range("A1"), LookIn:=xlValues, _
  LookAt:=xlWhole, SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
  MatchCase:=False, SearchFormat:=False)

If Not rng Is Nothing Then
    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range(rng.Offset(1, 0), rng.End(xlDown))
    ActiveSheet.Range("B1").Resize(rng.Rows, 1).Value = rng.Value 'put stored text starting in B1
End If



End Sub
```